# Multiple Question Marks appear when making a get request

Tags: c#, get, http-status-code-404, telegram-bot, webapi

I am writing a Telegram Bot as a project in my internship. It aims to help customers easily view reports on their company's sales and send them message notifications(using a Webhook).

For most of the reports, I make a request to an API I wrote which generates and returns them as a byte array/JSON Object. The expected result is a byte array, and that is the case for most of them.
However, one of the reports returns a 404 and contains multiple question marks in the Uri- which I did not add.
`https://url/?EpumpReport?/Company?/CompanyVarianceReport`

The expected behaviour is a 200 OK, and the pdf content.

I have tried initializing the HttpClient inside of the class instead of registering it in the Startup.
I have also tried sending the requests a different way by creating a HttpRequestMessage and sending that.
All to no avail.

I wrote this function to reduce clutter:
`GetReportWithSummaryDataAsync(message, Uri, _userData)`.
The message parameter contains a ChatId that identifies the user and a messageId that identifies the message.

```
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {userData.AuthKey}");

            var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);

            var response = await _client.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<SummaryData>(content);

            // Todo add check for NullReferenceException
            _pdfReport = new MemoryStream(result.pdfReport);
            return result;
```

This is the function itself. After this, I send the content of the result to the user.

The main issue is the Uri changing on its own.
Say I send a request to `https://google.com/example`, when the request is about to be/being sent, the Uri changes to `https://?google.com?/example?`
And, I don't know why.

Comment: Where you are having problem in this code?

Comment: at the point where the request is sent. `_client.SendAsync`. In the terminal, the URI that the request is sent to changes and has multiple question marks.

Comment: So, you are making request to that `Uri` parameter for PDF content and sending that response to `ChatId` ?

Comment: sending that response to a user with that `ChatId`, yes.

Comment: See [sendDocument](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument), that might what you are looking for.

Comment: I already use that. The main issue is the uri.
Say I send a request to `https://google.com/example`. When the request is about to be/is being sent, the Uri changes to `https://?google.com?/example?`
And, I don't know why.

Comment: Debug and Check from where you are passing `Uri` argument. Also, if you are sure about `Uri`, replace `?` with `Empty` string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there were hidden characters present in my URI string. A frontend dev in the company mentioned their experience with a similar issue; then, I used [this tool](https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/unicode-detector) to find and remove the characters from the string. It works as it should now.